# Ubuntu 14.04 hangs after login

Tags: 14.04

I am using ubuntu 14.04 on Dell inspiron with intel graphics card. I am intermittently getting this issue where after login I can't see anything on status bar and my system is not usable, after which I have to restart my machine(hard reboot). I have already referred : [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error).
Pressing ctrl+alt+F1 leads me to terminal which does not respond at all. I can only type into it and it does not have any effect. What are my options?

Comment: when did the issue start, or was it present since installation?

Comment: Do you really suspect that it's a graphics issue?  Do you know which driver you are using?

Comment: The symptoms are the same, so i feel it is the graphics card issue. I am not aware of the drivers that I am using. The issue is intermittent but it is present since installation.

Answer (score -2):

I posted a solution on other question ( on this pages).

First, my system has an Amd64 X2 and MB-Nividia Grafikchip.

Mint 17 and Ubuntu 14.04.1 installed, no windows.

The problem was solved by changing the grafikdriver to nvidia 3.04....

However to start up ubuntu the first time was tricky; I did it by selecting rescue in the boot menu, window grub repair, then resume normally.

After login the desktop came up.
From there I made the driver changed and update all. Now it's ok.
I made the change also on mint 17 . Also Mint works fine now.

Comment: Please link the driver you used.

Comment: @Horstb Are you saying you posted an answer [on that question](http://askubuntu.com/q/141606)? If so, it appears to have been with a different account; no answers there (not even any of the answers that have been deleted) were posted by this account. I recommend editing this answer to identify which answer you're referring to (you can link directly to it with the *share* link under the answer you wish to link to), and also to clarify precisely how that solution applies here. If this post is deleted in the mean time, you may be able to flag it for undeletion, or just post a new answer.